# web3.eth.accounts[i] alternative?

Tags: node.js, ethereum, blockchain, web3js, truffle

So in newer versions, the query

```
web3.eth.accounts;
```

is written as:

```
web3.eth.getAccounts();
```

What is the query to get the account at a particular index from the bunch of accounts?

In simple words, what is the new way of writing:

```
web3.eth.accounts[index];
```

Answer (score 0):

It returns the array of accounts as a promise, so you can wrap your code like this

```
  web3.eth.getAccounts().then((accounts) => {

     ...
     let a = accounts[index];
     ...
})
```